# deleting lines ( including blank lines )

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I am trying to delete the first 3 lines from the top of multiple .txt files with a batch file. The first and second lines contain text and the third is blank. I am trying to find a way to delete the lines according to their line number.

```
e.g Line 1 ABCD     
    Line 2 EFG
    Line 3
    Line 4 cool this works
    Line 5 line of text
    Line 6 line of text
    Line 7 
    Line 8 line of text
```

I have used the code below which works however, I have to give the variables as "keywords" and i want to use line numbers as variables. Also, for some reason the cursor is always creating a blank line at the top of each "new.txt" file made.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (C:\source\*.txt) DO (
TYPE "%%i"|FINDstr /l /v "ABCD  EFG" >> C:\newfiles\%%~ni.new
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: To delete the first 3 lines, use: `> "C:\newfiles\file.new" (for /F usebackq^ skip^=3^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("C:\source\file.txt") do echo(%%L)`

Comment: I gave it a bash however, It returns a blank file. I'll continue researching.

Comment: `more +3 input.txt>output.txt`, but it replaces TABs with spaces (which may or may not be a problem)

Comment: The Output is blank. Could possibly be the TABs..

Comment: `more /E +4 C:\a\*.txt >  C:\b\newfile.new` gives me the desired result minus the multiple file part XD.

Comment: `@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (C:\awe\*.eml) DO (
TYPE "%%i"| more /E +4 >> C:\5500\%%~ni.eml
)
goto :eof` got the job done. it removes the first 4 lines and then copys them all to C:\5500\ instead of to one file like all the other answers, Much thanks to Stephan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try for this code :

```
@echo off
set InPutfile=InputFile.txt
set OutputFile=OutPutfile.txt
(
    for /F "usebackq skip=3 delims= eol=" %%L in (`Type "%InPutfile%"`) do echo %%L
)>%OutputFile%
Start "" %OutputFile%
```

Comment: `for /F` would skip all empty lines, e.g. line 7 in given example. Moreover,  `… eol="` would _choke down_ all lines with leading `"`  double quote.